Search Reducer, searched items removed from redux store
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload)
      console.log(state)
    },
    deleteProduct: (state, action) => {
      // const {title} = action.payload;
      return state.filter(item => item.title !== action.payload)
    },
    searchProduct: (state, action) => {
      if (!action.payload.trim()) {
        return state
      } else {
        const res = state.filter(
          item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(
            action.payload.toLowerCase()
          )
        );
        return res
      }
    }
  }
})

export const {
  addProduct,
  deleteProduct,
  searchProduct
} = productSlice.actions
export default productSlice.reducer

Here when I search return search result, but after searching all other products that doesn't match the search query getting deleted from the store.
I need to display the search result when searching, and display all products if I am not searching.


Here when I search return search result, but after searching all other
products that doesn't match the search query getting deleted from the
store.

That's what Array.filter does, it filters values out of the source array and returns the new array, it's a reducing action, i.e it removes information. Once you filter it out, it cannot be unfiltered back in.
You probably don't want to mutate your source state if you are simply just wanting a filtered view of it though.
Instead of dispatching the searchProduct action to filter the state directly you should just filter the locally selected copy of the products array.
Example:
const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");
const products = useSelector(state => state.products);

const updateSearch = (value = "") => setSearch(value.toLowerCase());

const filteredProducts = React.useMemo(() => {
  return products.filter(
    item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search)
  );
}, [products, search]);

If you prefer computing and keeping the "filtered view" in the Redux store then add the search term to the Redux state and compute the filtered view in a selector function.
Example:
export const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    deleteProduct: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter(item => item.title !== action.payload)
    },
})

export const { addProduct, deleteProduct } = productSlice.actions;
export default productSlice.reducer;

export const productSearchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "productSearch",
  initialState: "",
  reducers: {
    searchProduct: {
      reducer: (state, action) => action.payload,
      prepare: (search = "") = ({
        payload: search.toLowerCase(),
      }),
    },
  },
});

export const { searchProduct } = productSearchSlice.actions;
export default productSearchSlice.reducer;

import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const selectProducts = state => state.products;

export const selectProductSearch = state => state.productSearch;

export const selectFilteredProducts = createSelector(
  [selectProducts, selectProductSearch],
  (products, search) => products.filter(
    item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search)
  ),
);

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const filteredProducts = useSelector(selectFilteredProducts);

const updateSearch = (value = "") => dispatch(searchProduct(value));

